# Functioning of Spring Boot Hibernate dialect properties?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Could someone explain what exactly this configuration does?

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

I found that the SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database or to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS.
For this particular example it is MySQL but what is the difference between Oracle DB or PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer

The dialect in the Hibernate context, will take care of database data type, like in oracle it is integer however in SQL it is int, so this will by known in hibernate by this property, how to map the fields internally.